# VirtualBox - no internet connection (answer: due to DNS)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns

I went through all the VirtualBox no internet topics on Super User, but could not find a working solution. The symptoms started following a corporate IT update, which I presume are one part of the issue, but as my answer below shows, not insurmountable.

**Host**: Windows 10
**Guest**: Ubuntu 16.04

**Virtualbox versions**:
5.2.6 - original working one
5.2.8 - did a clean install of this after initial issues
5.2.6 - reverted back to this known working version after 5.2.8 also didn't work

I tried every possible combination of the Network settings in the box (NAT, NAT Network, Bridged, and the adapter as virtualized, Intel Dual, Intel Desktop, etc, and Promiscuous allow all/deny), and also tried disabling+enabling the VirtualBox network config in Network Settings of Windows. But still the problem remained:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable

host google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

curl -v https://www.google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/  
* Could not resolve host: www.google.com  
* Closing connection 0  
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com

/sbin/route
Kernel IP routing table  
Destination    Gateway    Genmask   Flags  Metric  Ref    Use   Iface
```

Yes, the result of `/sbin/route` was empty except for the above headers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was related to the DNS nameserver setting in `/etc/network/interfaces`. In that file, I had this config for a month before the changes:

`dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8`

But then after the IT changes, this apparently blocked absolutely **everything** related to networking. I commented out the above line in the file and restarted the virtualbox. Magically I had full network access after that.

Since they are changes in the corporate settings, I am not aware what the changes were. But I didn't see any similar question to this one, where the answer was this, so I decided to add this one. In all other cases, it was usually about changing NAT to Bridged mode, but those didn't help in my case.

Hopefully it helps someone!